# Repair Macbook Keyboard

Tags: keyboard, hardware, repair

I have had a problem with my keyboard for over a year. Most of the time the letters between E and O don't work, so I'm forced to use another keyboard. I have noticed that pushing on the keys can help get them working again for a while. Therefore I think this is a hardware issue. I installed a new battery but it didn't help. I have blown compressed air around the keys with no luck.

The Macbook is a 15-inch, Mid 2012, i7 and I updated the RAM to 16gb and installed a 1TB SSD, two years ago. The laptop works really well if I could just get my keyboard working. I have found replacement keyboards, basically the front panel, on ebay and there not expensive so I'm tempted to try and replace it. Is there anything I can do to confirm that it is a keyboard hardware issue?

Answer (score 0):

Borrow a correctly-operating external USB keyboard, plug it into one of the MacBook's USB ports, and try it.

If no faults appear using the external keyboard, the MacBook's internal keyboard is faulty.